# Use reflection to loop over all available Icons

Tags: flutter, dart, reflection

Flutter provides an Icons class which defines a long series of available icons:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html#constants

I need the user to be able to set the icons for certain icon buttons, and I want to offer them a list of possibilities to chose from which includes all the available icons. Is it possible to generate such a list of `IconData` by somehow iterating over the static constants of the `Icons` class?

Comment: Maybe this link helps. Haven't tried it. https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-list-of-fields-and-methods-in-a-class

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of icons, for example.

```
    List<Icon> _icons = [
     Icon(
       Icons.account_circle_outlined,
       color: Colors.black,
     ),
     Icon(
        Icons.location_on_outlined,
        color: Colors.black,
     ),
     Icon(
       Icons.contact_support_outlined,
       color: Colors.black,
     ),

    ];
```

And then implement your method to select the icon from the above list.

Comment: This list would be several hundred entries long. I was hoping there was a way to generate this list instead with all possible Icons.

Comment: In that case, this way would be too unoptimised and hectic as well, but I do not know anyway to iterate through this class.